# Android, how to show active GPS coordinates in self-made app

Tags: java, android, xml, gps

Is there any code that lets you show your active coordinates in a self-made app? I am having troubles with my google maps and want to see what my active coordinates are. I prefer to show it as I am looking at the google maps in my app ie like a second layer of information. Thanks all !

Answer (score 3):

You can set up a LocationListener.

In the onLocationChanged callback, you will receive a Location. You can then .getLatitude() and .getLongitude() from the location, and apply it to your layout.

```
public class MyActivity extends MapActivity implements LocationListener {

    private LocationManager locationManager;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        requestFineAccuracyLocationUpdates();
    }

    private void requestFineAccuracyLocationUpdates() {
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
        criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);

        List<String> providers = locationManager.getProviders(true);

        for (String provider : providers) {
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 5000, 1000, this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        /* You can get your latitude and longitude here, and do whatever. */
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick awnsere, what do you mean put it in your layout? I have a on onclickListener with a string, and i set the .getLatitude and .getLongitude, but if i run it on my phone and i have a gps lock it will still pop back to coordinates 0,0. And i have the right permission (fine_location, and internet)

Comment: Do you have callbacks from a LocationListener in your MapActivity? Even if you have the location permission set, you need to request location updates from the LocationManager. I can update my answer with a quick example.

Comment: I will give a sample of my code tomorrow, its already 4 am here,im 15 :P if i wake up my parents they will be pissed,  thanks for the help !!